# How to colorize some words in text in ST2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to highlight a word in a text with a specific color. Or make it bold/italic/underlined.

Is there ST2 plugin allowing bolding/colorizing/italizing words in text?

Comment: Would you want to save it this way too? ST2 is not a rich text editor.

Comment: i also thought this may be a problem, but what about special tags? such as Markdown, may be not "colorizing" but at least "bolding". It could fold/unfold on double click...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plugin similar to Emacs orgmode(_http://orgmode.org/) would fit the request. There are several trials to port it to the ST: [here](https://github.com/demon386/SmartMarkdown), or [here](https://bitbucket.org/theblacklion/sublime_orgmode/src), although they seem to be in early stages and doesn't allow "colorizing".